# Running commands on docker container from the host

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Code first, it will be easier to explain what I'm after.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    user: '${UID}:${GID}'
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: foo
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/db
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/db
      - db-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro

  cache:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    sysctls:
      net.core.somaxconn: '511'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: ['--requirepass "secret"']

  api:
    image: node:alpine
    container_name: api
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    command: sh -c "npm start"
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/var/www/app/node_modules
      - .:/var/www/app
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache

volumes:
  node_modules:
```

**postgres** connection settings for `node.js` app:

```
export const {
  POSTGRES_USER = 'root',
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD = 'secret',
  POSTGRES_HOST = 'db',
  POSTGRES_PORT = 5432,
  POSTGRES_DATABASE = 'foo',
} = process.env
```

**issue**:

When using service or container name (`db` or `postgres`) for the `POSTGRES_HOST` setting of `node` app:

1. I can *successfully* connect to, and query, the database.
2. I'm *not able to* run commands from host which affect the container. For example, seeding db won't work:

   `npx knex --esm seed:run`

This makes sense, as the DNS resolution for `db` / `postgres` is taken care of by docker and those only have meaning on the network connecting the containers. Commands run from the host and targeting that container will fail as host doesn't know how to resolve the DNS here.

On the other hand, when using `localhost` for the `POSTGRES_HOST` setting of `node` app:

1. Queries to `postgres` from `api` will fail.
2. Commands run from the host, like `npx knex --esm seed:run`, will succeed.

Again, this makes perfect sense. Addressing container as `localhost` from host will work thanks to the port forwarding in `docker-compose.yml`. But in the context of the container, it refers to that very container: for `api` `localhost` means itself, and its trying to find a database on `localhost:5432` or `api:5432`.

I want to have working inter-container network and also run commands from the host, addressing the said containers. I'm aware of two approaches to achieve that:

1. Use container / service name as `POSTGRES_HOST`, and run commands against the containers with:

   `docker exec -it <container_name> <command>`
2. Assign static `ip`s to the containers and use those instead of service / container names.

Do I have any other options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are exposing the database ports on the host machine you can do the following.

- Use service or container name (db or postgres) for the POSTGRES_HOST, this way it will work for Docker containers.
- when you run the seed command form the host, overwrite the POSTGRES_HOST. This can be done in this way

```
$ export POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
$ npx knex --esm seed:run
```

or in one step

```
$ POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1 npx knex --esm seed:run
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this approach. It works just fine but - in my opinion - its neither elegant nor very portable.

Comment: I would say, the whole idea here is not realistic and only my apply to development environments. can you explain why do you need this?

Comment: Precisely that, the ease and comfort of development.

Comment: in case the issue is only with migration, you can switch to use a custom docker entry point that will execute the migrations and then start the server.  as a result, you only need to redeploy the container once you introduce a new migration and you would like to apply it

Comment: puls, using the env is your best choice here or using `docker-compose run or docker-compose exec `

Comment: these are all the options that are available AFAIK